# a new thread for running a cell in ipython/jupyter notebook

Tags: multithreading, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Sometimes it takes a long time to run a single cell, while it is running, I would like to write and run other cells in the same notebook, accessing the variables in the same context.

Is there any ipython magic that can be used such that when it is added to a cell, running the cell will automatically create a new thread and run with shared global data in the notebook?

Answer (score 13):

It may not be an answer, but rather the direction to it. I did not saw anything like that, still I'm interested in this too.

My current findings suggesting that one need to define it's **own custom cell magic**. Good references would be the *custom cell magic section* in the documentation and two examples that I would consider:

- memit: magic memory usage benching for IPython https://gist.github.com/vene/3022718
- Illustrating Python multithreading vs multiprocessing: http://nathangrigg.net/2015/04/python-threading-vs-processes/

Both those links wrapping the code in a thread. That could be a starting point.

**UPDATE:** ngcm-tutorial at github has description of background jobs class

```py
##github.com/jupyter/ngcm-tutorial/blob/master/Day-1/IPython%20Kernel/Background%20Jobs.ipynb
from IPython.lib import backgroundjobs as bg
jobs = bg.BackgroundJobManager()

def printfunc(interval=1, reps=5):
    for n in range(reps):
        time.sleep(interval)
        print('In the background... %i' % n)
        sys.stdout.flush()
    print('All done!')
    sys.stdout.flush()

jobs.new('printfunc(1,3)')
jobs.status()
```

**UPDATE 2:** Another option:

```py
from IPython.display import display
from ipywidgets import IntProgress

import threading

class App(object):
    def __init__(self, nloops=2000):
        self.nloops = nloops
        self.pb = IntProgress(description='Thread loops', min=0, max=self.nloops)

    def start(self):
        display(self.pb)
        while self.pb.value < self.nloops:
            self.pb.value += 1 
        self.pb.color = 'red'

app = App(nloops=20000)

t = threading.Thread(target=app.start)

t.start()
#t.join()
```

Answer (score 11):

Here is a little snippet that I came up with

```
def jobs_manager():
    from IPython.lib.backgroundjobs import BackgroundJobManager
    from IPython.core.magic import register_line_magic
    from IPython import get_ipython

    jobs = BackgroundJobManager()

    @register_line_magic
    def job(line):
        ip = get_ipython()
        jobs.new(line, ip.user_global_ns)

    return jobs
```

It uses IPython builtin module `IPython.lib.backgroundjobs` . So code is small and simple and no new dependencies are introduced.

I use it like this:

```
jobs = jobs_manager()

%job [fetch_url(_) for _ in urls]  # saves html file to disk
Starting job # 0 in a separate thread.
```

Then you can monitor the state with:

```
jobs.status()

Running jobs:
1 : [fetch_url(_) for _ in urls]

Dead jobs:
0 : [fetch_url(_) for _ in urls]
```

If job fails you can inspect stack trace with

```
jobs.traceback(0)
```

There is no way to kill a job. So I carefully use this dirty hack:

```
def kill_thread(thread):
    import ctypes

    id = thread.ident
    code = ctypes.pythonapi.PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc(
        ctypes.c_long(id),
        ctypes.py_object(SystemError)
    )
    if code == 0:
        raise ValueError('invalid thread id')
    elif code != 1:
        ctypes.pythonapi.PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc(
            ctypes.c_long(id),
            ctypes.c_long(0)
        )
        raise SystemError('PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc failed')
```

It raises `SystemError` in a given thread. So to kill a job I do

```
kill_thread(jobs.all[1])
```

To kill all running jobs I do

```
for thread in jobs.running:
    kill_thread(thread)
```

I like to use `%job` with widget-based progress bar https://github.com/alexanderkuk/log-progress like this:

```
%job [fetch_url(_) for _ in log_progress(urls, every=1)]
```

http://g.recordit.co/iZJsJm8BOL.gif

One can even use `%job` instead of `multiprocessing.TreadPool`:

```
for chunk in get_chunks(urls, 3):
    %job [fetch_url(_) for _ in log_progress(chunk, every=1)]
```

http://g.recordit.co/oTVCwugZYk.gif

Some obvious problems with this code:

1. You can not use arbitrary code in `%job`. There can be no assignments and not prints for example. So I use it with routines that store results on hard drive
2. Sometimes dirty hack in `kill_thread` does not work. I think that is why `IPython.lib.backgroundjobs` does not have this functionality by design. If thread is doing some system call like `sleep` or `read` exception is ignored.
3. It uses threads. Python has GIL , so `%job` can not be used for some heavy computations that take in python byte code

Comment: @minrk Could you please look at this answer and see if there any other problems with this solution that I did not think about?

Comment: What does "You can not use arbitrary code mean"? I'm trying to make a background job that updates the screen with an image it opens from the disk. I've also noticed that `time.sleep` "finishes" the thread.

Comment: awesome answer! was looking for something like this for ages