# Jupyter Notebook change variable during execution

Tags: python

I run a Jupyter Notebook (JupyterLab) which does some heavy computation in a loop for `e` episodes. DURING THE EXECUTION of the notebook I would like to set the counter `x`  close to `e`, so the loop will finish with the next iteration or so. Is that possible to change a variable at runtime? I would like to stop the this loop early but still execute the whole code of the notebook.

```
#stuff happening before
for x in range(e):
    #important calculations (takes forever)
#stuff happening after
```

The only way I know to stop the execution is to interrupt, where I would loose the data right?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Can you not use an `if` statement to `break` the loop at a certain value for `x`?

Comment: maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32081926/a-new-thread-for-running-a-cell-in-ipython-jupyter-notebook